# Equivalence of 2d quantum and topological gravity

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, topological-field-theory, matrix-model

I have heard of the statement that 2d quantum gravity (defined as minimal models of CFT coupled to Liouville theory) and 2d topological gravity are equivalent. The former is described by the continuum limit of the Hermitian one-matrix model, while the latter is the famous Kontsevich matrix model that generate intersection numbers. I have been trying to find a precise statement and proof of this statement? Are there are references for the same? What is the precise relation of their partition functions? In particular I am looking for the exact change of variables $t_i \to T_i$ of the partition functions,

$$Z_{quantum}(g_s, \{ t_i\}) \stackrel{?}{=} Z_{topological}(g_s, \{T_i \})$$

Comment: I suspect that this is the original result that you are referring to: [Intersection theory on the moduli space of curves and the matrix Airy function](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02099526).

Comment: Yeah, but I couldn't find a statement  like the one above in my question in that paper. Kontsevich proves it by showing that both the partition functions satisfy the KdV hierarchy with the same initial condition, so by uniqueness they are equal. But the precise relation between the partition function's themself is still mysterious to me.